# String aggregation in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report in SSRS 2008 and I want to combine some strings. I know you can write some code in SSRS to do this, but I'm not really sure how.

So basically I have the value "FullName" and I want to make it so it is FullName, FullName, FullName for the appropriate row. I am pulling the info from the appointment table using FetchXML. Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

EDIT: Make things clearer.

So I am querying from the appointment table and each appointment has more than one FullName, but they are in different rows in the Query. I want to combine them into the row they belong in the report

Thanks!

Comment: I'm unsure about what you are asking here. You want to group on some other field and display a coma separated list of `fullname` related to that group field? So if John, Jim and Rambo are of type 'soldier', you want to display a row with 'soldier : John, Jim, Rambo'?

Comment: So I am querying from the appointment table and each appointment has more than one FullName, but they are in different rows in the Query. I want to combine them into the row they belong in the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the JOIN function if you're attempting to put together a list of parameters.  Otherwise you would have to do it in the SQL with the STUFF function

http://lukehayler.com/2009/08/the-join-function-in-ssrs/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
=String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", Fields!FirstName.Value, Fields!FirstName.Value, Fields!FirstName.Value);
```

You can find more code expressions for SSRS [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx)

Just remember it uses VB.NET for its coding syntax.  You can also embed custom code in your reports for more complex operations

Answer (score 0):

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005) for details of how to concatenate values into a string across rows in SQLServer.